Railway - problems with connecting to postgres in production
Django worked perfectly locally, but had errors in production (I was using the same postgres DB and configuration).
Django server, hosted on Railway gave me this:

Newtorking tab in Postgres settings on Railway:
Postgres logs locally:
Settings: (WORKED PERFECTLY ON A LOCAL MACHINE WITH THIS IN-PROD DATABASE AND SAVED DATA)
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', //tried django.db.backends.postgresql, not working
    'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
    'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
  }
}
DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')

.env: (everything in {{}} is a variable)
DATABASE_PRIVATE_URL={{DATABASE_PRIVATE_URL}} //not using this
DATABASE_URL={{DATABASE_URL}}
DB_HOST=viaduct.proxy.rlwy.net
DB_NAME=railway
DB_PASSWORD={{DB_PASSWORD}}
DB_PORT=19232
DB_USER=postgres
SECRET_KEY={{SECRET_KEY}}

So I did:
<myname>@my-MBP django_project % psql -h localhost -l



                                   List of databases


   Name    |   Owner  | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges          
-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | <myname> | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0 | <myname> | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/<myname>                 +
           |          |          |         |       | <myname>=CTc/<myname>
 template1 | <myname> | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/<myname>                 +
           |          |          |         |       | <myname>=CTc/<myname>
(3 rows)




<myname>@my-MBP django_project % psql -h localhost -d postgres   
psql (14.11 (Homebrew))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

And got (On Railway):
Django server:

Postgres Database:

Doing this locally gives me the same error that was given in production
<myname>@my-MBP django_project % psql -h /var/run/postgresql -d postgres     
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

Again, before I ran psql -h localhost -d postgres everything was working perfectly on a LOCAL Django server. But in production, with the same configuration and database (hosted) it was not working.
